# Image Source Binding doesn't update inside ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a listview which has custom viewcell inside and viewcell have image control which is being bindded to ImageFile property

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage
             Grid.RowSpan="3"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             DownsampleToViewSize="True"
             Source="{Binding ImageFile, Converter={StaticResource byteToImage}}"
             Aspect="AspectFit">
          <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnTakePicture"/>
          </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

OnImage click i am changing the ImageFile source but Ui Doesnt get reflected

Note:- once i scroll down and come back it reflects the updated image.

Kindly provide a solution to resolve this.

Comment: Please add the model behind, on which you bind to. Maybe you don't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: @Joehl My Model class have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface... As i said property is updated properly even image is getting reflected after scrolling listview down and coming back up...

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange but the issue was with the MvvmCross property changed event...

I was using MvvmCross as mvvmhelper for my project but seems MvxViewModel doesnt behave well with notifyproperty changed event.

I have simply replaced with my custom implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface and this issue has been resolved